# Django: static files in a 404 template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, static-files, django-staticfiles

How to include stylesheets and images into a 404 page template using the default view?

I created a `404.html` file in the root of the site's `templates` directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% get_static_prefix %}css/404.css" />
</head>
<body class="page-404">
    <p>Not found.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ironically, the `404.css` is not found. The `404.css` file is located in one of the apps' `static` directory.

The server is `manage.py runserver`. On every other page static files are served just well.

*Update*: It appears, after setting `DEBUG = False` in the `settings.py`, static files on all other pages stopped being served, too.

Comment: which version of Django are you using? 1.3 ?

Comment: @Arthur Neves, 1.3, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, `staticfiles` app does work with `DEBUG = False`. Only it doesn’t pick up files from individual apps’ `static` directories. It would serve files from the global `STATIC_ROOT` directory (from `settings.py`).

To get the static files copied to `STATIC_ROOT`, you need to run the [`collectstatic` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic):

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

As contest_processor.static is in the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT already! you can just use the variable STATIC_URL in your template: follow doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-static

> If TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains this processor, every RequestContext will contain a variable STATIC_URL, providing the value of the STATIC_URL setting.

And we also know that the 404 view handler use a RequestContext Object, follow code took from django.views.defaults.py:

```
return http.HttpResponseNotFound(t.render(RequestContext(request, {'request_path': request.path})))
```

So just use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your template, it should work!

Comment: Thanks! I must have mentioned that I'm using `django.contrib.staticfiles` and it doesn't work with `DEBUG = False`. And if you set `DEBUG` to `True`, the 404 template won't be rendered. Anyways, `{% get_static_prefix %}` is equivalent to `{{ STATIC_URL }}`.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using DEBUG=True, I usually have this snippet in my root urlconf:

```
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```