# Create 404 with Django 1.4

Tags: django

I would like to show an 404 error if there's no proper entry in `project_name/urls.py`.

I read [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs#write-a-404-page-not-found-view) but i don't understood how to create a general error - not only for an app.

So i tried this:

1. `TEMPLATE_DIRS = /var/www/first/templates`
2. echo "404 ERROR" > /var/www/first/templates/404.html
3. in `/var/www/first/urls.py`:

   ```
   from django.http import Http404
   try: 
       ...
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       ... 
   except: 
       raise Http404
   ```

After all i still get a 500 error if i call an unknown url.

Comment: the default django behaviour is to show a 404 for unknown urls. if you have `DEBUG = True` it shows a debug view instead, but it shuold still indicate that you are viewing a 404 page. You do not need to raise `Http404` in your urls, it's handled at the framework level

Comment: do you have a handler404 and an associated view in your urls? `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404`

Comment: hm, if i set `DEBUG = True´ it shows me an 404. If `DEBUG = False´ i get 500 (Internal error).

Comment: you should remove definetly `try except` statements from urls.py file. Probably it is the reason of 500 error. Anyway Django should report about all 500 error to your email address (in ADMIN settings) with traceback and exact reason of error.

Comment: I had the same problem with `DEBUG = True`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7946180/352796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with following in `/var/www/first/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
...,
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
...,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the urls.py file to evaluate all the url patterns by order. If you want it to go to a certain page after it evaluated all the regex patterns and found no match, just add something like this as the last item in the `urlpatterns` tuple:

```
url('', views.defaultview),
```

with `defaultview` possibly being that 404 page.

`django.views.defaults.page_not_found` is a built-in django view that renders whatever's in `templates/404.html`.

Comment: I tried `url('', views.defaultview),` but this only works if i access my page without any path. If i try to open `mysite.tld` it shows me the defined view (404), but if i open `mysite.tld/fsdfk` i get the 500 again.